# Output of C code in which character is assigned an octal number

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{ 
  char a = 01212;
  printf("%d",a);
  return 0;
}
```

On compiling i get a warning and output -118 how? I know any number starting with 0 in c is considered as octal. The octal equivalent of 01212 is 650 then why the output is -118?

Comment: Won't fit......

Answer (score 1):

The assignment `char a = 01212;` on most of the systems is out of range and **implementation dependent.** A system with 8-bit `char` that implement 2's complement will print `-118`.

For detail, please read below explanation.

Unlike `integer` a `char` is not signed by default; there are three different char types in C.

`char`,

`signed char`

and

`unsigned char`

A `char` has a range from `CHAR_MIN` to `CHAR_MAX`. For a particular compiler, the `char` will use either an underlying signed or unsigned representation. You can check this value in `limits.h` of your system.
Here is the text from C99 standard point number **15**

> 6.2.5 Types
>
> The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are collectively called
>   the character types. The implementation shall define char to have the same range,
>   representation, and behavior as either signed char or unsigned char.35)

And again note **35** says

> 35) CHAR_MIN, defined in , will have one of the values 0 or SCHAR_MIN, and this can be
>   used to distinguish the two options. Irrespective of the choice made, char is a separate type from the
>   other two and is not compatible with either.

Having said this `char a = 01212;` is larger than 8 bit. The C standard allows char size more than 8 bit but I think almost all computers in today's world implement 8 Bit `char`.

So if `char` is implemented as unsigned char and the value is more than `CHAR_MAX` the value will be converted according to Modulo `CHAR_MAX+1`.

In 8 bit system, the converted value is 650 modulo 256 which is 650-512 = 138

If char is implemented as signed char the conversion is implementation dependent. If it's an 8-bit char system and it implements 2's complement the value will be `-118` as you have seen in your result. Note that in this system the Range for `char` will be from `-128` to `+127`.

Comment: DSPs commonly use 16-bit characters, as an example, but I think the take-away point here is that there's a lossy conversion happening, as the value `650` is greater than `CHAR_MAX` (`CHAR_MIN` is irrelevant, and not even guaranteed to exist)... I think it might be best to focus on answering the OPs question first and foremost, then delve into the alternatives... Don't you?

Comment: Modified as you said

Answer (score 1):

The value of `650` is most likely out-of-range for your `char` type. In C the behavior is *implementation-defined* in such cases as out-of-range integer conversions. I.e. it is clear that you will not get `650` in your `char`, and what exactly you will get depends on your compiler. Consult your compiler documentation to figure out why you got `-118`.

Comment: Nice answer. Very brief. Possibly too brief; you could afford to mention that the maximum value for `char` is specified by `CHAR_MAX` from `<limits.h>`... but not much more detail is needed, and I think this is one of those cases where "less is more".

Answer (score 0):

Char is only occupying one byte, or 8 bits, so the maximum number a unsigned char can hold is 2^8 - 1, which is 255, and a signed char has a maximum of 127. When assigned a number that's greater than that, it would cause undefined behavior, in which a negative number may appear.

Comment: It is not undefined behavior it is just cyclicity of char. Char a = 128 gives -128 as output so char a = 650 will give -118 accordingly. 650 is 522 greater than 128 so the output should also be 522 greater than -128 keeping in mind that char follows cyclicity property

Comment: Well, I said that before but was criticized by a lot of people. The same effect may not occur uniformly on all platforms. Got a lot of downvotes for that.... They call it "undefined behavior" or "implementation defined"

Comment: or do you mean that it is different for char and int? So that it is defined in C++ standard that the cyclicity rule much be followed?

Comment: I am beginner in c, that is the only  solution that crossed my mind. Probably other compilers will give different result

Comment: There's no undefined behaviour here. "undefined behaviour" and "implementation defined" are two different things

Comment: @Girish Arora: There's no such thing as "cyclicity of char" in C. When you perform out-of-range operations on signed types (and your `char` is signed), the behavior is either undefined or implementation-defined. In this case it is happens to be implementation-defined.

Comment: @Girish Arora it is implementation dependent.